# Not able to post data angular ng-resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to persist data using post method throught angular ngResource.
I have written the below code for the process. But, when I try to persist
error is coming.

JS CODE

```
angular.module('app').factory("testService", function($resource) {
return{ 
    addCount: $resource('/save/count',{method:'POST',params:{ date: '@date',
                    count: '@count'}}
        )
};
});
```

//controller code

```
$scope.add = function(){
testService.addCount().get({ date: new     Date(formattedDate).toString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
            count: count},function(response){
                console.log('success')

        });};
```

As soon as I click the add() from my html I am getting the below error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Kindly,provide a suggestion to overcome this issue

Comment: are you properly injecting the service in your controller?

Comment: try testService.addCount.get(....

Comment: Yeah I injected@chris

Comment: You're not using the $resource correctly. `'save':   {method:'POST'},` as per the documentation, if you want to post, you should use the method `save`

Comment: Also `testService.addCount()` don't call it as a function, an object is returned

Answer (score 0):

RESTful services should be on a per entity basis. So you route should just be `/Count` or `api/Count` depends on how you set up your API endpoints.

Then when you use your `$resource`, just point it at your endpoint and let `$resource` handle posting etc.

The `$resource` follows the meanings behind the HTTP verbs. So `GET` should get some data, `POST` should save data, `PUT` should update, `DELETE` should delete etc.

```
$scope.add = function(){
    var Count = $resource('/count');
    Count.save({
         date: new Date(formattedDate).toString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
         count: count
    }, function() {
        // success
    });
};
```

That is how I would see myself using `$resource`. You can always abstract out the creation of `Count` to the service you created.

---

## $resource

[Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

So when you call `$resource('some/route');` it will return an object containing these methods:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

As you can see, `save` is the `POST` method. So to call it you take a reference to `$resource('some/route');` like:

`var Count = $resource('some/route');`

Then you call a method.

> For a HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters],
>   [success], [error])
>
> For a non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData,
>   [success], [error])
>
> For a non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters],
>   [success], [error])

So as I understand it, class means that reference `Count`, instance means when your class has been executed and you've recieved the object. This object is the `instance`

Comment: I tried this , now the url is getting formed. But, I am getting bad request in console.                    ** POST http://localhost:8080/count?method=POST&params=%7B%22date%22:%22@date%22,%22count%22:%22@count%22%7D 400 (Bad Request)**

Comment: That means that your API backend is rejecting the request, what is your backend written in?

Comment: No, please check the request I have posted the dynamic values which I pass from controller are not getting binded to th eurl

Comment: This is the link you put on `http://localhost:8080/count?method=POST&params=%7B%22date%22:%22@date%22,%22count%22:%22@count%22%7D`

Comment: yeah exactly thats the url

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: I removed the the curly braces with parameters as you said but still the same error